# How to uninstall OneDrive/SkyDrive from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, onedrive

I hate OneDrive/SkyDrive for a lot of reasons. I want to uninstall it.
Unfortunately, neither OneDrive nor SkyDrive are not in the "*Uninstall or change a program*" list of the Control Panel.

**QUESTION:** How to uninstall OneDrive/SkyDrive?
*Windows 7 Enterprise 32bit*

*Note: There is a similar question for Windows 8, but the resolution for Windows 7 will be very different as there are no "Trusted Installer" problems at least.*

Comment: The simplest solution.  Download the installer, install it, then uninstall it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Could you please make this an answer and detail the last step? Thanks!

Comment: Which step?  you go to the control panel and hit uninstall.

Comment: @Ramhound: See the second line of the question. It is not in the control panel. Or do you mean that somehow installing it over (even though it is already installed) will magically make it appear there?

Comment: I read your question. Which is the reason I suggest you download the installer, attempt to install it, and if successful then uninstall it.